# add an element after the first element which passes a condition in a list

Tags: python, list, performance, loops

```
for i,k in enumerate(ls):
    if k == 3:
        ls.insert(i+1,"example")
        break
```

The above code iterates through a list `ls` and finds the first element that equals to 3 and inserts `"example"` after that element and stops. While the above code can be written as,

```
ls.insert(ls.index(3)+1,"example")
```

What is the most efficient way to write a program to enter a element after the first element that passes a condition such as,

```
    if k > 3:
```

or

```
    if isPrime(k):
```

Comment: Note that insertion in list is in O(n) and so not efficient. You should not do it in a loop for example. If you want to do that, then you need another data structure: a linked list, a deque or even more complex ones that are AFAIK not available in CPython built-ins modules. Rewriting the code to avoid inserts is the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an iterator for your condition and `next`:

```
ls = list(range(10))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

idx = next((i for i in range(len(ls)) if ls[i]>3),  # could be isPrime(ls[i])
           len(ls)) # default insertion in the end
ls.insert(idx+1, 'X')
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'X', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you don't want to insert if the condition is not met:

```
idx = next((i for i in range(len(ls)) if ls[i]>10), None)
if idx is not None:
    ls.insert(idx+1, 'X')
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

###### alternative

The one-liner equivalent of your code (with the same flaws in case of non match) could use `itertools.dropwhile` (note the inverted condition):

```
ls = list(range(10))
from itertools import dropwhile

ls.insert(ls.index(next(dropwhile(lambda x: not x>3, ls)))+1, 'X')
```

Output: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'X', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`